# Owin Bearer Token Not Working for WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, oauth, owin

I have gone through loads of documentation on this, My google search shows that I've visited all the links on the first page

**Problem**
Token Generation works fine. I configured it with a custom provider as such:

```
    public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var usermanager = NinjectContainer.Resolve<UserManager>(); 
        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
            Provider = new AppOAuthProvider(usermanager)
        });
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());
    }
```

However when I call a protected URL and pass the bearer token, I always get: [image: Token Request]

How do I diagnose or fix the problem. If possible, how can I do the token validation myself

**UPDATE**
Here is my AppOAuthProvider. Both Methods are called when I'm trying to mint a token but not when I'm trying to access a protected resource

```
public class AppOAuthProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
{
    private UserManager _user;
    public AppOAuthProvider(UserManager user)
    {
        _user = user;
    }
    public override async Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        context.Validated();
    }

    public override Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });

        //Get User Information
        var getUser = _user.FindUser(context.UserName);
        if (getUser.Status == StatusCode.Failed)
        {
            context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        }

        var user = getUser.Result;

        //Get Roles for User
        var getRoles = _user.GetRoles(user.UserID);
        if (getRoles.Status == StatusCode.Failed)
        {
            context.SetError("invalid_grant", "Could not determine Roles for the Specified User");
        }

        var roles = getRoles.Result;

        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("UserID", user.UserID.ToString()));
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("UserName", user.UserName));

        foreach (var role in roles)
        {
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role));
        }

        context.Validated(identity);

        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 2:** 
Here is my Account Controller

```
[RoutePrefix("api/auth/account")]
public class AccountController : ApiController
{
    private UserManager _user;
    public AccountController(UserManager user)
    {
        _user = user;
    }

    [Authorize]
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("secret")]
    public IHttpActionResult Secret()
    {
        return Ok("Yay! Achievement Unlocked");
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 3:**
Here is my Startup.cs

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseNinjectMiddleware(NinjectContainer.CreateKernel);
        app.UseNinjectWebApi(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        ConfigureOAuth(app);
        app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        app.UseWebApi(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        app.UseWelcomePage();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you use this tutorial: http://leastprivilege.com/2013/11/13/embedding-a-simple-usernamepassword-authorization-server-in-web-api-v2/
You also have to override ValidateClientAuthentication or else your request always gets rejected

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You must configure the OAuth authorization server and OAuth bearer authentication before call UseWebApi on IAppBuilder. The following is from my program.

```
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseFileServer(new FileServerOptions()
        {
            RequestPath = PathString.Empty,
            FileSystem = new PhysicalFileSystem(@".\files")
        });

        // set the default page
        app.UseWelcomePage(@"/index.html");

        ConfigureAuth(app);

        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute
        (
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional } 
        );

        config.Formatters.Clear();
        config.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings =
        new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
        };

        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        app.UseWebApi(config);


    }

    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions oAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
        {
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
            Provider = new YourApplicationOAuthProvider()
        };

        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(oAuthServerOptions);
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication
        (
            new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions 
            {
                Provider = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider()
            }
        );
    }
```

Comment: Great answer. I now know WHY it wasn't working. and in hind sight, it all makes sense. I now wonder what I was thinking.. `UseNinjectWebApi` registers WebAPI. I put it on above `ConfigureAuth` because I needed Ninject in my Authentication block.  @ojorma solution works because he re-registered WebAPI. thanks for the response

Comment: Thanks, I had the same issue, because I had the call to ConfigureAuth routine after the call to UseWebApi. Moving ConfigureAuth call to run before all other stuff inside Configuration routine fixed the problem.

Answer (score 3):

```
    HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
app.UseNinjectMiddleware(NinjectContainer.CreateKernel);
app.UseNinjectWebApi(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
ConfigureOAuth(app);
WebApiConfig.Register(config);
//GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
// app.UseWebApi(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
app.UseWebApi(config);
app.UseWelcomePage();
```

I tried this with ur sample application on github and it worked

Comment: Note, the ordering in this answer was critical in my app.  I'm using SimpleInjector, not Ninject, but I didn't need to use GlobalConfiguration.Configuration in the Startup class at all...just passing the created config instead was sufficient.  In the example above, it's still used in line 3.

Comment: @swannee Turns out that was the problem. Also, For DI to work, I had to move app.UseNinjectWebApi just before app.UseWebApi(config)

Answer (score 2):

In your provider you have to:

```
public override ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthClientAuthenticationContext context)
{
    //test context.ClientId
    //if you don't care about client id just validate the context
    context.Validated();
}
```

The reason for this is that if you don't override ValidateClientAuthentication and validate the context, it is assumed as rejected and you'll always get that error.

Comment: That's what I did and I still get "Not Authorized". I have updated the question to show my AppOAuthProvider class

Comment: @Ody Can you add a breakpoint in your GrantResourceOwnerCredentials method and make sure that is being hit?

Comment: Yes Both Methods are called when I'm trying to create a token and it works fine. However when I'm trying to access a protected resource, neither is called.

Comment: @Ody Can you show us your action method? Can you make sure it is annotated with the [Authorize attribute from System.Web.Http](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.authorizeattribute(v=vs.118).aspx)?

Comment: @Ody Those methods (GrantResourceOwnerCredentials and ValidateClientAuthentication) should only be invoked when getting the token, when you use the token it's the OAuthBearerAuthentication middleware that is used

Comment: I have updated the Question with Both the Action Method and Owin Pipeline.

I may end up replacing the provider for the OAuthBearerAuthentication

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60094/discussion-between-ody-and-rui).

Comment: Hi, If I care about client id, is there any good example to explain it ? @Rui

Comment: how to see access_token from context.response  before return to client?