# Owin OAuth2.0 PasswordGrant flow

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, owin

Question : Am I missing something here or misinterpreting what functions should actually be called?

So I've started out simple by creating a test WebApi project to implement OAuth2 using Owin.OAuth. Hitting the Route and stepping into the provider is no problem, but here is the code:
Startup Class:

```
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;

        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
            Provider = new OAuthProvider(),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60),
            AllowInsecureHttp = true
        });

        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());           

        WebApiConfig.Register(config);            
    }
```

And for now a barebones Provider class:

```
    public class OAuthProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
    {

    public override Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        return base.ValidateClientAuthentication(context);
    }

    public override Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        return base.GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(context);
    }
}
```

I'm looking to use a Password Grant https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3.2. Now according to the OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider docs the GrantResourceOwnerCredentials function is called when:

> Called when a request to the Token endpoint arrives with a "grant_type" of "password". This occurs when the user has provided name and password credentials directly into the client application's user interface, and the client application is using those to acquire an "access_token" and optional "refresh_token".

But when I hit the route it always goes into the ValidateClientAuthentication function.

Postman payload:

```
POST /Token HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:57507
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cache-Control: no-cache
grant_type=password&username=test&password=test123
```

Also tried using BasicAuth through Postman:

```
POST /Token HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:57507
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Authorization: Basic dGVzdDp0ZXN0MTIz
grant_type=password
```

Am I missing something here or misinterpreting how it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so I was interpreting the flow of the calls incorrectly when I asked this.

I was thinking that the first function to be called would be the `GrantResourceOwnerCredentials` when using a password grant. [OAuth Spec Doc Password Grant.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3.1) When in reality its always going to call `ValidateClientAuthentication` then the `GrantResourceOwnerCredentials`.

So this was just a misunderstanding on my part. This sample code was working.

Answer (score 0):

You need "describe" the method for validating credentials in body of `GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext)` method instead calling base method.
When you call `context.Validated(ClaimsIdentity)` method - you get bearer token in response.

There is question with good example of this - [see first code block in question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25483508/owin-bearer-token-not-working-for-webapi)

or You can see example [here](http://www.hackered.co.uk/articles/asp-net-mvc-creating-an-oauth-password-grant-type-token-endpoint)

ValidateClientAuthentication just validating your credentials "grant_type=password&username=test&password=test123"

Otherwise, your code looks ok.

Comment: Yes you are correct. I set this sample project up just to see if the project I was implementing it in was causing issues with routing. But I was just misinterpreting how it worked from the Docs.